# Spring MVC Thymeleaf Error: array element type mismatch

Tags: java, forms, spring-mvc, multidimensional-array, thymeleaf

The following code is supposed to generate a table of text inputs with the dimensions of a given 2d string array specified as a `ModelAttribute`. Additionally, each input's placeholder is its respective value in the array. The user then enters their own text values, and upon pressing "Submit Input" those values are outputted, in order, separated by spaces.

**InputHolder.java**

```
public class InputHolder {

    private String[][] input;

    public String[][] getInput() {
        return input;
    }

    public void setInput(String[][] input) {
        this.input = input;
    }

}
```

**GreetingController.java**

```
public class GreetingController {

    @ModelAttribute("string2d")
    public String[][] make2dStringArray() {
        return new String[][] {{"The", "quick", "brown"}, {"fox", "jumps", "over"}, {"the", "lazy", "dog."}};
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/greeting")
    public String recieveInput(final InputHolder inputHolder, Model model) {
        if (inputHolder == null || inputHolder.getInput() == null)
            return "greeting";
        String output = "";
        for (String[] row : inputHolder.getInput())
            for (String str : row)
                output += " " + str;
        model.addAttribute("output", output);
        return "greeting";
    }

}
```

**greeting.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Test Page</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/greeting" th:object="${inputHolder}" method="POST">
        <table>
            <tr th:each="row,rowStat : ${string2d}">
                <td th:each="string,stringStat : ${row}">
                    <input type="text" th:field="*{input[__${rowStat.index}__][__${stringStat.index}__]}" th:placeholder="${string}" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <button type="submit" name="submitInput">Submit Input</button>
    </form>
    <p th:text="'Output:' + ${output}"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Everything works up until I press "Submit Input", at which point I get the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: array element type mismatch
>       at java.lang.reflect.Array.set(Native Method)

Despite the fact that this is clearly a Java-side error, the error message isn't giving me a specific line number where the error occurred, and it doesn't pause in debug mode when the error occurs either. I don't know why this specific error is occurring since it appears to me that my object types (string, string array, 2d string array) are consistent/correct throughout my code, plus as I said I don't know where exactly the error is supposedly occurring.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found the error... I forgot to instantiate `InputHolder`'s `input` field.

Seriously unhelpful debugging though. There was no "type mismatch"; how about "null pointer" or "array index out of bounds"? A line number would have been nice too.